# Returning True if a sequence appears in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, boolean, sequence

I need to write a function that takes a list of ints `nums` and returns True if the sequence `1, 2, 3, ..` appears in the list somewhere.

My approach:

```
def list123(nums):
    num = ""
    for i in nums:
        num += i
    if "1,2,3" in num:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

it fails to work indicating: `builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

I would also like to know if there is a more simpler way, rather that converting the list to a string like i've done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get an error on `num += i`, because you are trying to add `1` to `""`. Instead, try the following:

```
def list123(nums, desired=[1, 2, 3]):
    return str(desired)[1:-1] in str(nums)
```

---

```
>>> list123([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
True
>>> list123([1, 2, 4, 3, 5])
False
>>> list123([1, 2, 4, 3, 5], desired=[2, 4, 3])
True
>>> list123([5, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 2, 3])
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def list123(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==1:
            if nums[i+1]==2:
                if nums[i+2]==3:
                    return True

    return False       


nums=[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]
print(list123(nums))
```

Comment: Please add some detail to the answer and make it more helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
def array123(nums):
  for i in range(0,len(nums)-2):
    if nums[i:i+3]==[1,2,3]:
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
def list123(nums):
    s = ''.join(str(x) for x in nums)
    if(re.search('123',s) != None):
        return True
    else:
        return False


nums=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(list123(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def array123(nums):
  num=''
  for i in nums:
    num += str(i)
  if num.count('1')>=1 and num.count('2')>=1 and num.count('3')>=1:
    return True
  else :
    return False
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    if 1 in nums and 2 in nums and 3 in nums:
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"
```

is there anything that i am missing or it can be written in this way without a for loop ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, the indentation of the code you have posted is invalid, and the answer is incorrect as it only checks for the presence of 1,2 and 3 in the code, whereas the OP wanted to check for the sequence `1, 2, 3`

Comment: Thanks for editing the indentation. It's still an incorrect solution to the OP's problem, though.